# ul li link not working (in navigation bar)

Tags: html, css

To help explain the situation, I pasted the code below. What's happening is for the nav buttons containing other lists inside of them (ul>li>ul), the link does not work, unless I click on the text specifically (doesn't work if I click on the outer areas of the button). It may be a bit confusing, but check out the jsfiddle below, and try clicking on the "About", "Why", and "Events" page. you'll see it only redirects to a new website if clicked on the text specifically.

What's the problem? I've tried countless things, and can't get it to work.

Here's the about tab. I've tried putting the a tag before the li tag, after the li tag, nothing seems to work.

```
 <li><a href="about.php">About</a>
  <ul>
    <a href="about.php#expectations"><li>Expectations</li></a>
    <a href="about.php#faq"><li>FAQ</li></a>
    <a href="laptopprogram.php"><li>Laptop Program</li></a>
  </ul>
</li>
```

The Jsfiddle in question: http://jsfiddle.net/hmourp8o/

Comment: yes, it redirects because of link, you should prevent them by using script...

Comment: Works fine for me . . .

Comment: Please validate your code https://html5.validator.nu/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this, added following css

```
nav#navbar li > a {
display: block;
height: 50px;
margin: 0px -35px;
padding: 0px 35px;
}
```

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hmourp8o/2/)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 problems:

1) The correct way to layout the html is to have the `<a>...</a>` within the `<li>...</li>` tags.
Once you have done this only the textual part of the button will be clickable.

2) So now you need to set the size of the `<a>...</a>` and ensure it fills the `<li>...</li>`

Usually I would do in css something like this:

```
a {
    display:inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    line-height ... etc
}
```

and now you can remove `padding` from the `<li>` elements, move transitions for hover etc onto the `<a>` tag etc. Generally you would be styling the links, rather than the list items. `<ul>` and `<li>` styles would be used for positioning mainly.

You'll have to fiddle around with some of the other css styles but this is the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

Because a tag is inline element, so it shows small area. You can add `display: block` to a tag. Then a tag will be block element.

Please see:

http://jsfiddle.net/hmourp8o/3/

```
#navbar a{
display: block;
}
```

Comment: Its not working for me... How did you get that to work?